# Pandas: add a 2-d arrays to the data frame without iterating over records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following `timeseries.data` in the following format:

```
[[1520582400.0, 58.333333333333336],
 [1520582520.0, 148.33333333333334],
 [1520582580.0, 259.6666666666667],
 [1520582640.0, 88.66666666666667],
 [1520582760.0, 52.333333333333336],
 [1520582820.0, 213.66666666666666],
 [1520582880.0, 98.66666666666667],
    :
    :
 [1520583000.0, 125.33333333333333],
 [1520583060.0, 191.0],
 [1520583120.0, 107.66666666666667]]
```

and I use the following code to put the data into a data frame `my_df`

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'value'])

for x in timeseries.data:
    my_df = my_df.append({'time': x[0], 'value: x[1]},ignore_index=True)
```

However, this is a bit slow. So I am wondering is there a way to put in all two columns directly into the data frame instead of iterating record by record? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the extremely simple equivalent, `pd.DataFrame(timeseries.data, columns = ['time', 'value'])`?

Comment: Another way to read @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's comment is "Do this: `pd.DataFrame(timeseries.data, columns=['time', 'value'])`"

Answer (score 1):

In anticipation of the next question....  Use `pd.to_datetime` to convert your time column to datetime values.  I use the `unit='s'` parameter because I recognize your `time` values as seconds from epoch.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'value'])
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')

df

                 time       value
0 2018-03-09 08:00:00   58.333333
1 2018-03-09 08:02:00  148.333333
2 2018-03-09 08:03:00  259.666667
3 2018-03-09 08:04:00   88.666667
4 2018-03-09 08:06:00   52.333333
5 2018-03-09 08:07:00  213.666667
6 2018-03-09 08:08:00   98.666667
7 2018-03-09 08:10:00  125.333333
8 2018-03-09 08:11:00  191.000000
9 2018-03-09 08:12:00  107.666667
```

---

**Setup**

```
data = [
    [1520582400.0, 58.333333333333336],
    [1520582520.0, 148.33333333333334],
    [1520582580.0, 259.6666666666667],
    [1520582640.0, 88.66666666666667],
    [1520582760.0, 52.333333333333336],
    [1520582820.0, 213.66666666666666],
    [1520582880.0, 98.66666666666667],
    [1520583000.0, 125.33333333333333],
    [1520583060.0, 191.0],
    [1520583120.0, 107.66666666666667]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a duplicate, but couldn't find an appropriate one. If anyone were to answer this question, I'd prefer you did it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd add a little bit more information in an attempt to be useful (-: